# Find user details by ID in nested object nodejs | javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, nested-object

How to find name using id. means iterate object. create a function `const searchName =()=>{}`
suppose if pass 3 in function so I'd want to show .... what the name of user like this

```
const data = [{
    "service": [
        "BUSINESS",
        "LEGAL",
        "FINANCE",
        "ADVERTISEMENT"
    ],
    "service1": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "a" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "b" },
        { "id": 3, "name": "c" },
        { "id": 4, "name": "d" },
    ],
    "service2": [
        { "id": 5, "name": "e" },
        { "id": 6, "name": "f" },
        { "id": 7, "name": "g" },
        { "id": 8, "name": "h" },
    ],
    "service3": [
        { "id": 9, "name": "i" },
        { "id": 10, "name": "j" },
        { "id": 11, "name": "k" },
        { "id": 12, "name": "l" },
    ],
    "service4": [
        { "id": 13, "name": "m" },
        { "id": 14, "name": "n" },
        { "id": 15, "name": "o" },
        { "id": 16, "name": "p" },
    ],
}
]
```

suppose user pass `3` so I want to return  `{ "id": 3, "name": "c" }` like this.
I'm trying to iterate this and find the name of the user by id but I didn't understand this iteration so I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code.... Enter any id number

```js
const data = [{
                    "service": [
                        "BUSINESS",
                        "LEGAL",
                        "FINANCE",
                        "ADVERTISEMENT"
                    ],
                    "service1": [
                        { "id": 1, "name": "a" },
                        { "id": 2, "name": "b" },
                        { "id": 3, "name": "c" },
                        { "id": 4, "name": "d" },
                    ],
                    "service2": [
                        { "id": 5, "name": "e" },
                        { "id": 6, "name": "f" },
                        { "id": 7, "name": "g" },
                        { "id": 8, "name": "h" },
                    ],
                    "service3": [
                        { "id": 9, "name": "i" },
                        { "id": 10, "name": "j" },
                        { "id": 11, "name": "k" },
                        { "id": 12, "name": "l" },
                    ],
                    "service4": [
                        { "id": 13, "name": "m" },
                        { "id": 14, "name": "n" },
                        { "id": 15, "name": "o" },
                        { "id": 16, "name": "p" },
                    ],
                }]
            var itemobj = ''
            const searchName =(val)=>{
                    console.log('searchname')
                    data.map((item)=>{
                        let obj = Object.keys(item)            
                        obj.map((data)=>{
                            let inrdata = item[data]
                            inrdata.map((initem)=>{                    
                                 let lastdata = initem.id===val?itemobj=initem:null  
                                  
                                
                            })

                        })
                    })
                }
                
            searchName(3)
             console.log(itemobj)
```

Comment: Quite complex... could you add explanations to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchName(id) {
let result = null;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (key === "service") continue
    result = value.filter(obj => {
        return obj.id === id
        })
    if (result) break
  }
  return result ? result[0] : null
}
```

I iterate through keys, I just skip "service" one since it's not revelant.
Then, I filter the "service**N**" array, it will return an array of object (only one if found, empty array if not found).

If it's found, we stop iterating.

Then we return either the first (and logically only element) or null if not found

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get get the user by id

```js
function searchName(id) {
  return data
    .flatMap((item) => Object.values(item))
    .flat()
    .find((user) => user.id === id);
}

const result = searchName(3); // { id: 3, name: 'c' } | undefined
```